# Как посчитать разницу между временными точками внутри группы при группировке?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, group-by

Имеется фрейм, в котором есть столбец `time` (`datetime64[ns, UTC]`) и столбец `ID` (`int64`), содержащий ID предметов. `ID` дублируются, потому что у них разные значения в столбце time. Количество дубликатов варьируется от 2 до >30.

Нужно понять, в следствие чего возникает эта разница и если она, условно, меньше 1 дня - это случай А, а если больше - случай Б. Для этого, как я понимаю, нужно посчитать разницу между значениями time для каждого ID

Мне понятно, что для этого нужно сгруппировать по столбцу `ID`, но я не знаю как посчитать разницу между максимальным и минимальным временем внутри группы.

Какую функцию аггрегировать? И повлияет ли на это количество дубликатов?

На выходе хотел бы получить фрейм, со столбцами `ID` и `Diff_dd` (разница между датами в днях).

[Ссылка на образец фрейма в csv](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/AzKvO888xyicQw)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
df["tag"] = \
    (df
     .groupby("ID")
     ["time"]
     .transform(lambda x: "A" if (x.max() - x.min()).days < 1 else "B"))
```

результат:

```
In [17]: df
Out[17]:
                                time              ID tag
0   2021-02-10 12:48:47.219679+00:00  16192451275000   A
1   2021-02-10 12:48:52.400780+00:00  16192451275000   A
2   2020-10-06 08:41:51.018953+00:00  16389299849000   A
3   2020-10-06 08:41:51.879025+00:00  16389299849000   A
4   2020-10-06 08:41:52.563313+00:00  16389299849000   A
..                               ...             ...  ..
995 2020-12-23 15:57:09.970337+00:00  20035780455000   A
996 2020-12-23 15:57:10.387862+00:00  20035780455000   A
997 2020-12-23 15:57:10.831439+00:00  20035780455000   A
998 2020-12-29 14:03:55.819637+00:00  20037163637000   A
999 2020-12-29 14:03:55.763292+00:00  20037163637000   A

[1000 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Так работает 